# Number of Reduced Fractions with Denominator d in (C)

Tags: c, math

I've been working on this kata for a whole day. 
well my code is working now good;

but i need to reduce the time which this code takes to execute and an other problem that this code doesn't work with big 
numbers like **long d = 9999999999**;

so i wish someone helps me with this problem
by the way this is the challenge that i am doing;

https://www.codewars.com/kata/number-of-proper-fractions-with-denominator-d/train/c

and I am trying to solve it with **Euler's Totient** formula as it shown in ma code;
here you can understand how **Euler's Totient** works.

https://www.dcode.fr/euler-totient

thanx in advance.

```
int is_prime(long num)
{
  long i = 2;
  if (num == 1) return 0;

  for (i; num >= i * i; i++)
      if (num % i == 0) return 0;
  return (1);
}

long properFractions(long d)
{
  long sum = 0;
  long i = 2;
  long double v1 = 1.0; 
  long keep = d;

  for (i; i <= d; i++)
      if(d % i == 0 )
         if (is_prime(i))
             v1 *= (1.0 - (1.0 / i));

  if (keep != 1)
     sum = (keep * v1);
  return (sum);
}
```

Comment: You have implemented a particularly slow factoring method by using your isPrime method. Instead, modify your code to **first** find the prime power factorization of d, and then computing Euler's phi function. Also, don't compute the phi function the way you are doing it, instead use only integer arithmetic. You'll find the wikipedia discussion of Euler's Phi more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find co-primes less than `n`.

```
n = p1^x1 * p2^x2 * ... * pn^xn
phi(n) = p1^(x1-1)*(p1-1) * p2^(x2-1)*(p2-1) * ... * pn^(xn-1)(pn-1)
```

Now look even for a big number you will get all primes in iterating upto `sqrt(n)` numbers. Once you do it employ power calculation (`O(logt)` in case of `a^t`). This will fetch you a AC.

Comment: could you please explain me what x means;

Comment: @HeIs.:`36 = 2^2*3^2` so here `x1=2` and `y1=2 , p1=2,p2=3`.

Comment: yes i get it and `phi(36) = (2^1 * 1) * (3^1 * 2) = 12`

Answer (score 2):

> code doesn't work with big numbers like long d = 9999999999;

This is due to 2 causes: insufficient range should `long` be 32-bit and `long*long` overflow.

1. To certainly work with values like `9,999,999,999` (a 34-bit value), be sure to use 34+ - bit math.  Suggest `unsigned long long` which is at least 64-bit.
2. Avoid the test `num >= i * i` as `i*i` can readily overflow.  Use `num/i >= i`.<sup>1</sup>

Instead:

```
int is_prime(unsigned long long num) {
  if (num <= 1) return 0;// Handle 0,1

  unsigned long long i = 2;
  for (i; num/i >= i; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

There are *many* performance improvements possible with prime determination.  Yet this should get code past the "doesn't work with big numbers".

---

<sup>1</sup> Good compilers will see the nearby `num/i` and `num%i` and often compute them together for about the same time cost as one individually.

Comment: yeah this is useful and i can remove the second line because **num** is always >= 2.